# Unbalancing weights on an inclined plane with pulleys

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Richard Feynman uses the following figure in [Chapter 4.2](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html#2) of his lectures:

[image: Fig 4.3]

Then he goes on to explain why $W$ must weigh 3/5 of a pound for the system to be in balance. There are two explanations and I understand them both. The first applies the principle of conversation of energy, so if between states (a) and (b) the top weight moved 3 distance units up and the bottom weight moved 5 distance units down, we know that weight $W$ has to equal $3/5 lbs$. The second explanation involves [the epitaph of Stevinus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246664/understanding-feynmans-argument-about-stevinus), which is even easier to visualise.

Fine, but I'm a noob and there's something I don't understand. Why does the system have to be *in balance*? Wouldn't the top weight be in the exact same position if we increased the weight of $W$? In my mind, I picture this as the top weight colliding with the pulley and stopping there.

I reckon that there should be a threshold above which the rope breaks, but let's suppose that we increase the weight of $W$ just a little bit.

Comment: The system does not need to be *in balance*, which means that nothing moves (strictly, nothing accelerates). If $W>\frac35lb$ then $W$ will accelerate down and the $1lb$ weight accelerates up the slope. Opposite happens if $W<\frac35lb$. However if $W=\frac35lb$ then you can deduce that nothing moves = the system is *in balance.* Conversely if nothing moves then you can deduce that $W=\frac35lb$. ... The rope breaking has got nothing to do with this. Feynman is assuming the $1lb$ block does not touch the pulley.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. How would you square your explanation that if the system is in balance then nothing moves with this statement of Feynman's: "If we say it is just balanced, it is reversible and so can move up and down".

Comment: If $W=\frac35lb$ then there is no *acceleration* up or down but the system could still move with (any!) *constant speed* up or down or stay still. All 3 options are consistent with zero acceleration.

Comment: @sammygerbil I think your first comment is actually the answer already

Comment: Yeah @sammygerbil if you could post both the first comment and the second to account for the "no acceleration" bit I will mark the answer as accepted.